# Ampersand not displayed correctly in top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

In the new top bar the reputation (mouse over) tool tip displays the ampersand in **Science Fiction & Fantasy** as: `&amp;`

[image: mouse over tool tip]

Comment: What's wrong with `&amp;`? All I see is blonde, br....ok fixing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oops, fixed in the next build.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-oops]? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd they just won't let me add that one, even though I try and bring it up at least monthly

Comment: Thanks Nick, great service!